# Search an HTML Class for a String and Play a Sound if it Exists

Tags: javascript, html

Currently trying to make something with Javascript that searches for a string in an HTML class, then uses an if statement to play a sound if it exists.
Looks something like this:

```html
<div class="chat-msg"><span>test</span></div>
```

```js
var sound = new Audio('something.mp3');

var chatsound = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-msg");

if (chatsound.indexOf('test') !=-1)
{
 sound.play();
}
```

Keep in mind I've never used Javascript before, so I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: What is the problem, what is the question?

Comment: @CodeiSir I'm trying to get the sound to play, but it doesn't seem to find the word 'test' within the class. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's what I thougt, just keep in mind to have a Question in your question to not get wrong answers or even get the Question closed. See my answer below, I hope it helps. If not please leave a comment on my answer.

Comment: You have to iterate over the chatsound collection. Please see the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, the path to the Audio-File is correct, this should work:

```js
var sound = new Audio('something.mp3');

var chatsound = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-msg")[0].textContent;

if (chatsound.indexOf('test') != -1) {
  sound.play();
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-msg"><span>test</span></div>
```

Not too bad what you did, just two things:

- `getElementsByClassName` return an Collection of elements, to get the first use `getElementsByClassName("chat-msg")[0]`
- to get the text of a HTML-Element use `.textContent`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is there a way I can make it play right the message is sent? It only seems to work right now when I execute the script.

Comment: Yes, you have to call this when you send the message. I have no idea how your code looks like, so you would have to show me

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM may have similar elements with same class. So you need to loop over them and check if it has the targeted text. `document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0]` will only return the first item of the collection and will fail if your DOM is like below html

HTML

```
<div class="chat-msg"><span> I have diff text</span></div>
<div class="chat-msg"><span> Hello </span></div>
<div class="chat-msg"><span>test</span></div>
<div class="chat-msg"><span>text 2</span></div>
```

JS

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-msg'); // get the elements

// loop through the elements
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].textContent.indexOf('test') > -1) {
       var sound = new Audio("http://robbbenson.com/01%20The%20Artist%201.mp3");
       sound.play();
    }
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/0xbqmrcf/2/)