# Play a sound when a trigger word is shown

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to play a sound when its trigger word is shown on the page, but with no success.

Here's a snippet of the code

```js
var elements =  document.getElementsByClassName('message');

var triggers = [ 
  {
    name: "turtle",
    sound: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/jump.ogg"
  },  
  {
    name: "water",
    sound: "http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/explosion%2001.wav"
  }  
];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].name.indexOf(elements) > -1) {
       var sound = triggers[i].sound;
       sound.play();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='message'>
  <p>A turtle was in the pond</p>
</div>
```

Comment: did you get sound to play when using a single file and running the play() on it ?

Comment: What's `triggers[i].name.indexOf(elements)` supposed to do?

Comment: I should have added I have been following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843600/search-an-html-class-for-a-string-and-play-a-sound-if-it-exists and tried to add more triggers but pretty sure I messed it up

Comment: Keep in mind some browsers block auto-play audio without any interaction (play button for example): https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio

Comment: Oh, yes thanks for the reminder! I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqv6fp75) that I made, which I will explain here

Here's the updated JS code

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('message');

var triggers = [{
    name: "turtle",
    sound: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/jump.ogg"
  },
  {
    name: "water",
    sound: "http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/explosion%2001.wav"
  }
];


// fetch all the '.message' elements first
for (let message of elements) {
    // retrieve the HTML node text
  const text = message.innerText;
  // cycle through all triggers
  for (let trigger of triggers) {
         // find related ones
    if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(trigger.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        // create a new 'audio' object
      const track = new Audio(trigger.sound);
      track.load();
      // play it
      track.play();
    }
  }
}
```

You can have a look at the Web Audio API docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)

Comment: @Nicoletta fixed broken link, even if it will be without comments :)