# Problem with multiple audio on top of each other on Javascript

Tags: javascript

Following up my last question : [Play a sound when a trigger word is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267199/play-a-sound-when-a-trigger-word-is-shown)

I incorporated the code and it works perfectly, until I generate more triggers and they all stack on on top of each other's. Also when a new trigger is shown in the page, the old trigger starts playing as well.

> example:
>
> CAT is shown ---> meow
>
> DOG is show -----> meow + bark

but when bark plays I do not want meow to play as well. If it already played it should not play.

this is the audio part of my code where I generate the sound

```
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".robotMessage");
    for (let message of elements) {
    const text = message.innerText;
    for (let trigger of triggers) {
      if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(trigger.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        const track = new Audio(trigger.sound);
        track.load();
        track.play();
        track.volume = 0.5;
     }
    }
   }
```

A part of my audio:

```
var triggers = [
                 {
                   name: "skating",
                   sound: "https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/sports/skateboard_kick_push.ogg"
                 },

                 {
                   name: "rollerblading",
                   sound: "./sounds/Rollerblading.mp3"
                 },

                 {
                   name: "walk",
                   sound: "https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/foley/walk.ogg"
                 },

                 {
                   name: "walking",
                   sound: "https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/foley/walk.ogg"
                 }];
```

Is there a way to fix it? I've been researching for days but I cannot find a good solution to it. Is there a way to maybe go around it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are reading all the triggers again, when you're supposed to read just the last one. Try this way:

when trigger is added:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".robotMessage");
var message = elements[elements.length-1]; //get last message
const text = message.innerText;

for (let trigger of triggers) {
   if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(trigger.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        var track = new Audio(trigger.sound);
        track.load();
        track.play();
        track.volume = 0.5;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect and fast solution for my days' long problem! Thank you